# Finding biggest K numbers from a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I have an list of objects in scheme. Each object is associated with a confidence value that can be calculated at runtime. I want to find the top 50 such objects with the highest confidence value.
Example: `((WordPair1) (WordPair2))` and so on are my objects.

They are randomly ordered. I have written a function that takes these WordPairs as objects and returns a confidence value. Now, I want to find the top 50 such objects with the highest confidence values.

I can find out the object with the highest value of confidence but I am stumped on how to find the top K objects.

How can this be done?

Comment: Just sort the confidence values, then `take` *k* of them.

Comment: Sorting is also a problem. There are almost 500,000 of them. I need to get the object also. So I will have to store the object with the confidence value as a list. When I try to do that, I get a stack overflow error.

Comment: Just zip them together with `(map list ...)` or `(map cons ...)`. Also, if you're writing properly tail-recursive functions, you shouldn't be getting a stack overflow error.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the `(map list)` part?

Comment: You can use `map` on multiple lists, which will pass an element from each to the provided function. Try evaluating `(map list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))` to see what I mean.

Comment: Okay, but for that, I will still have to construct a list of confidence values. For 500,000 values, won't that lead to stackOverflow?

Comment: No, but it could use a lot of memory and be inefficient. There are better solutions, yes, but that's outside the scope of this comment thread.

Comment: I'll add another question regarding that.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I don't know any approach to this in Scheme. I run intoo implementation problems.

Answer (score 3):

Create a priority queue of length 50. Insert each confidence value as it appears in the input stream; if the new value is smaller than the smallest of the 50, let it fall out the bottom of the priority queue. When you have seen the entire input the values that remain in the priority queue will be the 50 largest.

Comment: I know this approach. The problem is the Scheme implementation.

Comment: I give an implementation at [http://programmingpraxis.com/2014/08/01/kth-largest-item/](http://programmingpraxis.com/2014/08/01/kth-largest-item/).